# OIDC redirect loop issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, istio, okta

Env:

Istio: 1.14.1

Okta

OAuth2-proxy: v7.2.0

K8s: 1.21.11

Followed this https://www.jetstack.io/blog/istio-oidc/ to setup OIDC auth for my application. I am running into redirect loop issue. I see this error in the oauth2-proxy pod logs

```
[2022/07/06 17:20:56] [oauthproxy.go:862] No valid authentication in request. Initiating login.
```

Any help to troubleshoot this? Please let me know if you need more details about the setup.

Comment: Is there anything else in the oauth2-proxy log (for example the HTTP request)?

Comment: That looks like a cookie issue. Check browser console errors and if cookies are properly propagated to the pod.

Comment: @PeterClaes I see this one  2022/07/11 14:16:57] [cookies.go:21] Warning: request host "home.xx-yy.com:31922" did not match any of the specific cookie domains of "home.xx-yy.com" and then a lot of these chars "2525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252Fauthorization-code%2525252525252525252525252525252Fcallback%2525252525252525252525252525253Fcode%2525252525252525252525252525253D6L46DJ9Fj7BgyhznDX3NyB-BBSaTY2jAUGI_PmQjZM8%25252525252525252525252525252526state%2525252525252525252525252525253 in the callback HTTP request

Comment: @janGaraj, I dodn't see any errors in the console log.

Comment: It is cookie issue. Configure that "cookie domain" properly

Comment: Perhaps oauth2-proxy is struggling with the port (31922)

Comment: i configured the cookie domain but without the port, I still get the same mismatch error

Comment: any further advice?